# access data frame column using variable

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the following code

```
a = "col1"
b = "col2"
d = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
```

This code produces the following data frame

```
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

However the desired data frame is

```
  col1 col2
1 1    4
2 2    5
3 3    6
```

Further, I'd like to be able to do something like `d$a` which would then grab `d$col1` since `a = "col1"`

How can I tell R that `"a"` is a variable and not a name of a column?

Comment: You can't use `$` like that. [**See here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18228613/1478381) for more information on why. You can however do `d[ , a ]` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Try out this code. Any idea how to avoid this error, or what this error is?     columnName = "col1";
    value = 5;
    
    d = data.frame();
    d[,columnName] = value;

Comment: You have an empty data frame. There is no variable "columnName" in it, so you can't call it or assign a value to it.

Comment: So how can I fix this so it works? I want to start with an empty data frame

Comment: I suppose you could start w/ `d = data.frame(NA)`, although you'd always have a column of `NA`s in your data frame. I don't usually start w/ an empty data frame.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After creating your data frame, you need to use [?colnames](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html).  For example, you would have:

```
d = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6))
colnames(d) <- c("col1", "col2")
```

You can also name your variables when you create the data frame.  For example:

```
d = data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3), col2=c(4,5,6))
```

Further, if you have the names of columns stored in variables, as in

```
a <- "col1"
```

you can't use `$` to select a column via `d$a`. R will look for a column whose name is `a`. Instead, you can do either `d[[a]]` or `d[,a]`.

Comment: In case of `data.frame`, `names(d)<- c("col1", "col2")` will do.

Comment: That's a good point, @Metrics. In truth, I almost never use `names()`; `colnames()` seems conceptually clearer to me. Is there some benefit, other than typing 3 fewer characters?

Comment: You are correct @gung. That also holds if you want consistency :)

Comment: @Metrics, consistency in what sense? A `list` doesn't have `colnames`, but a `data.frame` is a type of a `list`. On the other hand, `data.frame`s are similar to a rectangular `matrix` which has `colnames` and `rownames`.... Sigh...

Answer (score 11):

You can do it  this way

```
a = "col1"
b = "col2"
d = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))

>d
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

#Renaming the columns
names(d) <- c(a,b)
> d
  col1 col2
1    1    4
2    2    5
3    3    6

#Calling by names
 d[,a]
```