# R dataframe filter by column name in variable

Tags: r, dataframe, var, col

Word of notice: my experience with R is SO small.

I need to extract all columns from a dataframe, filtering by column "id" with value of `2`, but having column "id" in a variable, not hardcoded.

There's a couple of related questions, but I couldn't infer the solution out of them:

[How to use a string variable to select a data frame column using $ notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717397/how-to-use-a-string-variable-to-select-a-data-frame-column-using-notation)

[access data frame column using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730806/access-data-frame-column-using-variable)

My code:

```
df            <- data.frame(id  = c(1,2,3) , col_a=c("A1","A2","A3") , col_b=c("B1","B2","B3"))
pk_single_col <- "id"
#how do i translate this instruction NOT to use $id, but the variable pk_single_col?
spameggs      <- df_a[df_a$id %in% 2 ,]
```

Thank you SO much in advance!

Comment: You can use `[[` as mentioned in the answer - `spameggs  <- df[df[[pk_single_col]] %in% 2 ,] `

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, @ronak I couldn't figure it out myself